# What is platform useragent of the windows platfom?

Tags: c++

I am posting the requesting request uisng "POST" method, In mac platform uaser agent is 
10.6.2. But the in windows waht is platform user agent.

Comment: why do you need the user agent?

Comment: And why the hell is it tagged with c++ ? However trusting the user agent is a very very bad idea. And this question is way too unclear to really make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user agent string depends solely on the browser or whatever client you are using to make the request. It has nothing to do with the operating system, though most browsers will include some information about the OS version.

For example, on my version of Firefox it is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0b7) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0b7
```

and on IE6 it is:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
```

Here, `Windows NT 5.1` represents the OS version.

Comment: Can i use this one as the user agent string Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.16) Gecko/20101130 Firefox/3.5.16 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)

Comment: @Mahantesh: What do you mean by "can I use"? Are you writing your own client -- if so, yes, you can use any string you want.

Comment: But when i use  this as user agent string , The internetreadfile always retuns -1, but i want 0 .

Comment: @Mahantesh: Edit your question and post your code there so that we can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use Internet Explorer's user agent. And IE's user agent is depending on what software you have installed, by installing download manager, the software will appen its ID into the user agent, for IE & firefox, (depending on the download manager).

To know what is your useragent, in address bar of IE or FF type : `javascript:alert(navigator.userAgent)`

In the dialog box press Ctrl+C to copy the content

Answer (score 0):

```
hINetOpen = InternetOpen(_T("SplashID"),  INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);//AK
    if (hINetOpen != NULL){
        hINetConnect = InternetConnect(hINetOpen, sServerName, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, INTERNET_FLAG_IDN_PROXY, 0); 
        if (hINetConnect != NULL){
            hINetRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hINetConnect, _T("POST"), sObjectName, HTTP_VERSION, 0, NULL,  INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD |INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID | SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTO_REDIRECT | INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE, 0);
            if (hINetRequest != NULL){                      
                if(HttpSendRequest(hINetRequest, strHeaders, strHeaders.GetLength(), (LPVOID) StrFormdata.GetString(), StrFormdata.GetLength())) {
                    CString sBodyText;
                    DWORD nRead= 1024;
                    char szBuf[ 1025 ] = {0};
                    while ( nRead > 0 ) {
                            // Read in a temporary buffer
                        InternetReadFile(hINetRequest, szBuf, 1024, &nRead);
                        szBuf[nRead] = '\0';
                        sBodyText = szBuf;
                        result =  atoi(szBuf);
                        break;  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```